# Visual C# And Microsoft Access 2007

Tags: c#, ms-access

[image: See this image]

The `DataGridView` is updating but `Contacts.accdb` is not changing.

I want it to change it, Can you help?

Solved :

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.contactsTableAdapter.Fill(this.contactsDataSet.Contacts);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = contactsDataSet.Contacts;
    try
    {
        DataRow row = contactsDataSet.Contacts.NewRow();
        row[0] = contactsDataSet.Contacts.Rows.Count + 1;
        row[1] = "Dsatasdasfo";
        row[2] = "Maisgfdgdfuradze";
        row[3] = 596110800;
        row[4] = "Tserefgdfgdteli Ave, Building 10";
        contactsDataSet.Contacts.Rows.Add(row);
    }
    catch (ConstraintException error)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(error.Message,"Error",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    }
    finally
    {
        contactsTableAdapter.Adapter.Update(contactsDataSet.Contacts);
    }
}
```

Comment: It would make it easier for us to help if you took the time to paste the code into your question. The image is not searchable and it is likely to disappear in the future breaking this question irredeemably.

Comment: Your title means nothing, since the question has little to do with "Access 2007" and "Visual C#" would not make a significant title. Please update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't persist the changes back to the database in your code, you need to call:

```
ContactsDataAdapter.Update()
```

Comment: thx thx tha :) :D i've not reputation to thumb up ur answer it worked for me

Comment: @user2132375 You can accept the answer by clicking the tick below!